# How to set active tab in Primefaces tabview by it's id?

Tags: primefaces

Is there any way I can set active tab programmatically by it's ID, not index? Tabs in my tabview changes dynamically, and the only way I can reliably refer to them is by ID.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem ?

Comment: Not really. And I am not coding in JSF/PF anymore so its kinda lost the urgency...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

You can get the tab index for a given tab id by doing this in javascript:

```
function getTabIndex(tabId) {

    var tabLinks = $('#tabViewId li a').toArray();

    for(var tabIndex = 0; tabIndex < tabLinks.length; tabIndex++) {
        if($(tabLinks[tabIndex]).attr('href') == ('#tabViewId:'+ tabId)) {
            return tabIndex;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Then once you got the index you can do:

```
tabView.select(tabIndex)
```

Answer (score -1):

You do this using

You pass in the active id dynamically for p:focus component

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/focus.jsf